# propTypes isRequired constraint mis-leading behaviour in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to react( or to say web technologies). I started building an app which uses different components. When I went through the documentation, I thought putting `isRequired` in propTypes, constrains the user to provide all `isRequired` attributes when using the component.

But, in this example even if I don't pass `isRequired` attributes I'm able to load the component.

```
var PanelPreview = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
       return { captionIndex: 0 };
    },
    propTypes: {
       beforeSrc: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
       afterSrc: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
       captionTable: React.PropTypes.array
    },
});
module.exports = PanelPreview;
```

app using this component:

```
   React.render(
      < PanelPreview />,
      document.getElementById('main')
   );
```

I want to constrain the user of the component to provide these two values else throw some sort of error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Props failing validation isn't currently considered a critical error. However there will be a warnning logged in the console:

```
Warning: Required prop `beforeSrc` was not specified in `PanelPreview`.
```

This only happens in a non-production build of react. In production nothing is logged. See this fiddle for an example http://jsfiddle.net/5mafp3eu/1/

There has been discussion about having React fail-fast for prop validation failures (see issues below), it seems like it's going to happen eventually, but I don't think it's on any roadmap yet.

- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1587
- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1753

Comment: @mAc just to add to this, FB recently released Flow for type-checking JS, http://flowtype.org. It handles prop types as you were expecting (but unfortunately it doesn't look like it's a simple addition to any setup)