# Force ReactJS to throw real errors when propTypes validation fails?

Tags: javascript, validation, continuous-integration, reactjs

At present, if `propType` validation fails, ReactJS uses `console.warn` to emit a warning. I really, really want a real error in dev mode, so it can fail our continuous integration build, instead of just printing a message that might be lost in the shuffle.

There's already been discussion of this, e.g. in [this feature request](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1587), and this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908918/proptypes-isrequired-constraint-mis-leading-behaviour-in-react) describes the current behavior as expected. That's fine, but **I personally want it to throw an error.**

Assuming that ReactJS doesn't provide better support for this any time soon, **what's the best workaround?** So far, the best I've come up with is to override `console.warn` for tests, e.g.

```
console.warn = function(msg) {
    throw new Error(msg);
};
```

The downside of this is, it can be tricky to implement in tests, and it's not React-specific, so other `console.warn` calls also need to be handled.

Comment: one guess of mine would be to make a grunt / gulp plugin to replace console.warn with .error?

Comment: Do you have any news on this? I also want the validation to throw an error.

Comment: I went with overriding `console.warn` in development, using a blacklist of regex patterns to check for errors. It wasn't elegant, but worked properly to fail my tests.

Comment: I would love for there to be a setting somewhere that enables exception throwing for proptype validation. Most obvious - to me - would be to make this a feature of the React DevTools.

Comment: is there any update on this? I really need it too

Comment: The two answers here are the only ones I’ve found: use Flow, or override console methods in your test setup. Neither is a perfect solution, unless you’re using Flow anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FlowType, introduced by Facebook yesterday sounds like exactly what you're after. It can analyse your code, infer types, and throw errors at compile time.

It specifically includes support for React and the propTypes argument: https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/

Update (July 21) - Link above fixed, but given Facebook's recent change on Flow to heavily prioritise internal use over future community use, would recommend TypeScript instead for new projects. Example:

https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/class_components/

Comment: Looks interesting, though I'm still trying to figure out the dependencies. I'll look into it, though, thanks!

Comment: Marking this as the right answer - many years later, I’d always suggest Flow or Typescript for this

Comment: Link is dead. -

Comment: @FabianPicone Fixed the link now

Answer (score 13):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29654112/372479), you can check the error message against typical react messages and only throw for those. Not perfect, but maybe a step closer to what you're looking for:

```
let warn = console.warn;
console.warn = function(warning) {
  if (/(Invalid prop|Failed propType)/.test(warning)) {
    throw new Error(warning);
  }
  warn.apply(console, arguments);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

React 17 - throw in test

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  const { error } = console;
  jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation((...args) => {
    const message = args[0].replace('%s%s', '').replace('%s', args[1]) + args[2];
    if (/(Invalid prop|Failed prop type)/.test(message)) {
      throw new Error(message);
    }
    error.apply(console, args);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -4):

```
function TodoProvider(props) {
  const [items, dispatch] = useReducer(todoReducer, initialItems);
  const todoData = { items, dispatch };
  return <TodoContext.Provider value={todoData} {...props} />;
}
```

Comment: How is this related?